# When I try to invoke method "calcArea", error message "non-static method calcArea() cannot be referenced from a static context" appears

Tags: java

I've messed around with this for an hour now and can't get it to work. I've also looked this question up but the wording used in answers I've found haven't helped me at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, the invocation in question is at the very end of the program, inside *main*.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Area {

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void areaTriangle (double height, double length){
   System.out.println((height * length) * .5);
}

public static void areaRectangle (double height, double length, 
        double width){
   System.out.println(height * length * width);
}

public static void areaCircle (double radius){
  System.out.println(Math.PI * (radius * radius));
}

  public void calcArea (){
    double i;
    System.out.println("Which shape's area would you like to calculate?: \n"
    + "Enter '1' for Triangle \n"
    + "Enter '2' for Rectangle \n"
    + "Enter '3' for Circle \n"
    + "Enter '0' to quit the program");

    i = input.nextDouble();

    if (i == 1)
    {
            System.out.print("Enter the height of your triangle: ");
            double height = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter the height of your length: ");
            double length = input.nextDouble();

            areaTriangle(height, length);
    }
    else if ( i == 2)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the height of your rectangle: ");
        double height = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the length of your rectangle: ");
        double length = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the width of your rectangle: ");
        double width = input.nextDouble();

        areaRectangle(height, length, width);
    }
    else if ( i == 3)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the radius of your circle");
        double radius = input.nextDouble();

        areaCircle(radius);
    }
    else if ( i == 0)
        return;
    else
        System.out.println("Please input a number from 0 - 3");


  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    calcArea();
  }

}
```

Comment: Make your `Scanner` and the method `static`.

Comment: thank you very much! I'd removed the static from calcArea and forgotten about it, but didn't know I should make my scanner static. I'm fairly new with java and I'm still trying to grasp the meaning of certain keywords and what they do. I know the definition but I still have trouble with knowing exactly what they are.

Comment: Pasting the error message you got in google would have returned tons of links explaining what the error means. Google is your friend. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

put static in calcArea

```
public static void calcArea ()
```

or you can do this in your main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     YourClassName variable= new YourClassName();
     variable.calcArea();
    }
```

just change the **"YourClassName"** to the name of your **class** and also you can change the **variable** object